# DateTime series of Years months weeks and mins ago

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know quite exatly what im doing in my example but what i need my function to return is a string that is represented like this

```
1yr, 2 months or
1yr or
2months or
2months 2weeks or
3mins ago
```

if someone knows how todo this then please leave a answer

```
private string GetTimeSpan(DateTime creationDate)
{
    string timespan = "";
    if (Math.Floor(DateTime.Today.Subtract(creationDate).TotalDays / 365.25) >= 1)
    {
        timespan += ((int)Math.Floor(DateTime.Today.Subtract(creationDate).TotalDays / 365.25)).ToString() + "yr, ";
    }
    else if (Math.Floor(DateTime.Today.Subtract(creationDate).TotalDays / 365.25) < 1)
    {
        timespan += ((int)Math.Floor(DateTime.Today.Subtract(creationDate).TotalDays / 365.25)).ToString();
    }

    return timespan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.DateTime` has the [`-` operator overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx), which takes two `DateTime`s (since it's a binary operator) and returns a `TimeSpan` instance:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - someOtherTime;
```

That should get you a `TimeSpan` which represents the time between the two `DateTime` instances.  To print out a string that you want, you can do something like this, via an extension method:

```
public static string Print(this TimeSpan p) 
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  if(p.Days > 365)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}yr, ", p.Years / 365);
  if(p.Days % 365 > 30) // hard-code 30 as month interval...
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}months, ", ( p.Days % 365 ) /30);
  if(p.Days % 365 % 30 > 7) 
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}weeks, ", p.Days % 365 % 30 / 7);
  if(p.Days % 365 % 30 % 7 > 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}days, ", p.Days % 365 % 30 % 7);
  if(p.Hours > 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}hr, ", p.Hours);
  // ... and so on ...
  sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2); // remove the last ", " part.
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
string span = (DateTime.Now - creationDate).Print();
```

Comment: Thanks for you're reply I'll give that ago, have you tested it? the only part is the hard coded 30 for month where some have 31 that my only concern if you know how to fix that update you're code

Comment: When dealing with a calendar, yes, a "month" can vary from 28 to 31 days.  When dealing with a time interval, a "month" is whatever you define it to be since it's really just shorthand.

Comment: Um where starts with p.Years it doesn't recognize Years so would I put p.TotalDays / 365

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DateDiff** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2009, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  // > Date1: 08.11.2009 07:13:59
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
  // > Date2: 20.03.2011 19:55:28

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );

  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(1): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 1 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(1): 1 Year
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(2): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 2 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(2): 1 Year 4 Months
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(3): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 3 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(3): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(4): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 4 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(4): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(5): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 5 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(5): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours 41 Mins
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(6): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 6 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(6): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours 41 Mins 29 Secs
} // DateDiffSample
```