# How to implement Since method

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I was looking for a method that display dates like in stackoverflow

something like :

- **1 hour ago**
- **2 minutes ago**
- **Just now**

Etc...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509372/datetime-series-of-years-months-weeks-and-mins-ago/9542025#9542025)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a method to do so :

```
    static string GetPrettyDate(DateTime d)
    {
        // 1.
        // Get time span elapsed since the date.
        TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d);

        // 2.
        // Get total number of days elapsed.
        int dayDiff = (int)s.TotalDays;

        // 3.
        // Get total number of seconds elapsed.
        int secDiff = (int)s.TotalSeconds;

        // 4.
        // Don't allow out of range values.
        if (dayDiff < 0 || dayDiff >= 31)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // 5.
        // Handle same-day times.
        if (dayDiff == 0)
        {
            // A.
            // Less than one minute ago.
            if (secDiff < 60)
            {
                return "just now";
            }
            // B.
            // Less than 2 minutes ago.
            if (secDiff < 120)
            {
                return "1 minute ago";
            }
            // C.
            // Less than one hour ago.
            if (secDiff < 3600)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} minutes ago",
                    Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 60));
            }
            // D.
            // Less than 2 hours ago.
            if (secDiff < 7200)
            {
                return "1 hour ago";
            }
            // E.
            // Less than one day ago.
            if (secDiff < 86400)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} hours ago",
                    Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 3600));
            }
        }
        // 6.
        // Handle previous days.
        if (dayDiff == 1)
        {
            return "yesterday";
        }
        if (dayDiff < 7)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} days ago",
            dayDiff);
        }
        if (dayDiff < 31)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} weeks ago",
            Math.Ceiling((double)dayDiff / 7));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Source : http://www.dotnetperls.com/pretty-date